# Dynamic menu from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, menu

Hey I have question about Dynamic menu which is created in php. 
Code is from stackoverflow, what I want is to get my parent styled with red color if children of those parent is selected, here is code:

```
$menu = Array(
    Array(
        'title' => 'Home',
        'link' => 'a'
    ),
    Array(
        'title' => 'Parent',
        'link' => 'b',
        'children' => Array(
            Array(
                'title' => 'Sub 1',
                'link' => 'c'
            ),
            Array(
                'title' => 'Sub 2',
                'link' => 'd'
            ),
        )
    )
); 
function buildMenu($menuArray)
{
    foreach ($menuArray as $node)
    {
        $selected = ($node['link']== $_GET['menu']) ? $selected = 'style="color: red;"' : null;
        echo "<li ".$selected."><a href='?menu=".$node['link']."'/>" . $node['title'] . "</a>";
        if ( ! empty($node['children'])) {
            echo "<ul>";
            buildMenu($node['children']);
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
buildMenu($menu);
```

So how it needs to go:

Home
Parent - selected
Sub 1 - selected
Sub 2

or

Home
Parent - selected
Sub 1
Sub 2 - selected

Hope someone understand what i want? If my children under parent is selected also parent needs to be selected.

Comment: give the style to anchor instead of li

Comment: that makes no difference.

Comment: What is the content of $_GET['menu']?

Comment: I get link which page is opened with $_GET['menu']

Comment: So $_GET['menu'] would contain values like a,b,c,d right?

Comment: Yes if i select Home it will be a, if i select b it will be Parent selected etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added one function to check element in children array. May be something better solution are there. But at this its quick solution for you :)

```
$menu = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Home',
        'link' => 'a'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Parent',
        'link' => 'b',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Sub 1',
                'link' => 'c'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Sub 2',
                'link' => 'd'
            ),
        )
    )
);

function buildMenu($menuArray) {
    foreach ($menuArray as $node) {

        $getMenu = isset($_GET['menu']) ? $_GET['menu'] : '';
        $checkParent = (isset($node['children']) && !empty($node['children'])) ? checkInChildArray($getMenu, $node['children']) : '';
        $parentSelected = ($checkParent) ? $selected = 'style="color: red;"' : null;
        echo "<li " . $parentSelected . "><a href='?menu=" . $node['link'] . "'>" . $node['title'] . "</a></li>";
        if (isset($node['children']) && !empty($node['children'])) {

            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($node['children'] as $subMenu) {
                $childSelected = ($subMenu['link'] == $getMenu) ? $selected = 'style="color: red;"' : null;
                echo "<li " . $childSelected . "><a href='?menu=" . $subMenu['link'] . "'>" . $subMenu['title'] . "</a></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
}

// Checking if selected menu inside children array. 

function checkInChildArray($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item['link'] === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && checkInChildArray($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


echo buildMenu($menu);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UBDSAh)</kbd>

Comment: Still doesnt select my parent of my childrens.

Comment: Ahh. I see . Let say if d is `$_GET['menu']` value then d should display in red color and its parent as well. right?

Comment: Yes if Sub2 is selected than Parent needs to be also selected, but is not.

Comment: @user3278890 . Check my current solutions

Comment: Now is working but only on item D on item C doesnt select Parent and also if u use only parent doesnt select Parent

Comment: Ok fix that select also only Parent, only problem is now that first Children wont selected parent also on second or third it works ok. Here is demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Gpy8ER if i select first Sub 1 in Parent1 it wont select Parent1 but on selecting Sub2, Sub3 works perfect.

Comment: I have modified `checkInChildArray` function. Now it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to add parent li a background color

```
$('li.selected').parent().closest('li').css("color","red");
```

Comment: I would like to add class to li throught php if its possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Pass every menu level to the url. You can add the "selected" class for every menu level. So:

```
$current_menu_level_1 = (isset($_GET['menu_level_1'])) ? $_GET['menu_level_1'] : false;
$current_menu_level_2 = (isset($_GET['menu_level_2'])) ? $_GET['menu_level_2'] : false;
```

When building your menu, compare the 'to be build item' to the $current_menu_level1/2 variable and add echo the class when they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

please, consider create a css class selected for `<li>` elements and `<ul>` elements.

With PHP insert this styles when needed, Like this:

```
$selected = ($node['link']== $_GET['menu']) ? $selected = 'selected' : '';
echo "<li class='".$selected."'>";

echo "<ul class='".$selected."'>";
        buildMenu($node['children']);
echo "</ul>";
```